Javascript - SubtleCrypt - SHA1 Hex
I'm researching ways to validate that a password has been pwned or not. Part of the process is to get the SHA-1 hash of the password (I know - not secure - but this is just a first crude attempt at a larger project). I ran across the SubtleCrypto page that covers the digest() method and I am getting values from it - sort of - but am stuck-ish at a particular part.
async function digestMessage(message) {
            const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message); // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
            const hashBuffer = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-1", msgUint8); // hash the message
            const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); // convert buffer to byte array
            const hashHex = hashArray
            .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
            .join(""); // convert bytes to hex string
            return hashHex;
        }
digestMessage(password).then((digestHex) => console.log(digestHex));

The last line is where the trouble is. I'm using JS (executed by some very simple HTML), and I can set the value of an HTML element to see the result (by replacing console.log(digestHex) with document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = digestHex), but what I would prefer to do is to set digestHex (what I am assuming is holding the result) to a variable. I've tried different methods:
const output = "";

//take 1
digestMessage(password).then((digestHext) => output = digestHex);

//take 2
output = digestMessage(password).then((digestHex) => digestHex);

//take 3
digestMessage(password).then((digestHex) => { output = digestHex });

But I can't seem to set digestHex to a variable, even though setting the value of an HTML element works fine - I either get nothing in the variable or it's set to a promise object. I'm very very new to promises and am super rusty with JS, so any help would be appreciated. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I am at a loss lol
TIA!

I think await is what you want. output = await digestMessage(password)

Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question and not a list of tags. Also take the [tour].

@GeneralGrievance I did start to try that, but I was prompted with the message that 'await' can only be used in async functions. I did create another async function and tried your suggestion in there, but the output variable still remained blank.

OK, I think the issue is here then. Use a module script (requires localhost server if you want to test), or if you can't do that, wrap it all in the top-level async function.

Example of the latter: https://jsfiddle.net/3m8seLrh/
